# C++ Qt QtConcurrent::filteredReduced from QVector of std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

I have a `vector` of `shared_ptrs` of my `class Person`, which looks like:

```
QVector <std::shared_ptr<const Person>> vecOfPeople;
```

One of Person's field is `age` and I want to calculate with `QtConcurrent::filteredReduced` for example how many there are people over `50` and I find it very difficult to understand how to do it. I have a `bool` returning function `isOver50` as:

```
bool isOver50(std::shared_ptr<const Person> &person)
{
    return person->getAge() > 50;
}
```

And if I understand good, there should be also a `reduction` function, which at my code looks like:

```
void reduction(int &result, std::shared_ptr<const Person> &person)
{
    result++;
}
```

And finally, code with `filteredReduced` as:

```
QFuture<int> futureOver50 = QtConcurrent::filteredReduced(vecOfPeople, isOver50, reduction);

futureOver50.waitForFinished();

qDebug() << futureOver50.result();
```

This doesn't compile, my bet is there's something wrong in `reduction` function, but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentfilter.html):

> The filter function must be of the form:
>
> ```
> bool function(const T &t);
> ```
>
> ---
>
> The reduce function must be of the form:
>
> ```
> V function(T &result, const U &intermediate)
> ```

Your `shared_ptr` arguments are non-constant references (even though the pointed-to type is constant) where Qt wants to pass a constant reference, leading to a compilation error.

Instead, consider using

```
bool isOver50(const std::shared_ptr<const Person> &person);
void reduction(int &result, const std::shared_ptr<const Person> &person);
```

---

<sup>In the future, please try to submit the actual error message along with your question, it makes diagnosing these issues a lot faster</sup>